# Reorder bars in a bar graph Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js for a project, and I created a horizontal bar graph, whose data is to change according to various inputs. Is it possible to make it so that the bars "rearrange" themselves in ascending or descending order ?

For the moment I'm using a quicksort algorithm to reorder the data and associated labels, but as a result the labels just "change", I would prefer to have an animation showing the bars "reordering".

My other problem is that the bars are WAY too large : I reduced their thickness but the chart is huge and there is a lot of space between bars that I don't know how to reduce.

Here is my code :

```
const CHART = document.getElementById("chart");

Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 3000;

let barChart = new Chart(CHART, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: ['France', 'United Kingdom', 'USA', 'New Zealand', 'Spain', 'Denmark'],
        datasets: [
            {
            label:"Index",
            data: [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()]
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                barThickness: 30
            }]

        }
    }
});

function swap(labels, data, i, j) {
   // Labels
   tmpL = labels[i]
   labels[i] = labels[j];
   labels[j] = tmpL;
   // Data
   tmpD = data[i];
   data[i] = data[j];
   data[j] = tmpD;
}

function partition(labels, data, left, right) {
   var pivot = data[Math.floor((left + right)/2)];
   var i = left, j = right;

   while (i<=j) {
        while (data[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }
        while (data[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swap(labels, data, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    return i;
}

function quickSort(labels, data, left, right) {
    var indexPivot = partition(labels, data, left, right);
    if (left < indexPivot - 1) {
        quickSort(labels, data, left, indexPivot - 1);
    }
    if (indexPivot < right) {
        quickSort(labels, data, indexPivot, right);
    }
    console.log(labels);
    return data;
}

function show() {
    for (var i = 0; i<barChart.data.datasets[0].data.length; i++) {
        barChart.data.datasets[0].data[i] = Math.random();
    }
    barChart.data.datasets[0].data = quickSort(barChart.data.labels, barChart.data.datasets[0].data, 0, barChart.data.datasets[0].data.length - 1);
    barChart.update();
}

setInterval(show, 5000);
```

Thank you very much !

Tom.